# "Vegetable garden" instead of "garden" in a translation

Tags: british-english, translation

A Croat author wrote

> The garden was the mirror of familiy pride, where everything was planted, from flowers to edible fruits.

A British English native translated it into English like this:

> The vegetable garden was the mirror of familiy pride, where everything was planted, from flowers to edible fruits.

My question is, why *vegetable*?

Comment: The translator assumed that the garden was more a vegetable one. Vegetable garden - a small garden where vegetables are grown.

Comment: To include vegetables, I suppose, and to contrast it to a "flower garden" or an orchard. You could ask as well, "Why 'edible'?" How many people plant *inedible* fruits in their garden? Don't most fruits (besides tomatoes) grow on trees and not in gardens? But you are right: without more information in the Croat original, "vegetable" sounds superfluous and should be removed from the translation (in my opinion). Perhaps the translator's dictionary described the Croat word as a "vegetable garden."

Comment: Without "vegetable," doesn't "garden" in BrEn translate roughly to "lawn" in AmEn?  As for inedible fruits- the fibers in rose hips are the main ingredient in some itching powders, but people still plant roses in their gardens.

Comment: @Mark Do you not have trees in your garden? Apart from the fact that many fruits (most berries, for example) grow on bushes rather than trees, having an apple tree or a peach tree in your garden is perfectly common where I’m from (and I’m guessing presumably in Croatia as well).

Comment: The interesting thing about the translation is that the garden is *not* just for vegetables, because the end of the sentence says it's for both flowers and vegetables. I suspect @jejorda2 is correct about the BrEn nuance.

Comment: @Barmar I don’t think so. I think the translation is simply wrong. A garden is a garden in Britain as well, regardless of whether it’s just an uncultivated, plain lawn or an elaborate Japanese garden. I would expect both flowers and edible fruits (apple, orange, olive, and cherry trees, for example, but also perhaps bushes with berries) in a garden, but not in a vegetable garden. In a vegetable garden I’d expect potatoes, leeks, chives, parsley, sage, rosemary, and thyme, etc., but neither flowers nor fruit trees. The excerpt here looks like it’s describing a garden, not a vegetable garden.

Comment: (Note that the actual quote itself doesn’t mention vegetables at all.)

Comment: Excellent points all, Janus! My garden consists of several hearty stands of five or six varieties of vigorous bamboo. I have no talent for growing much else. :-)

Comment: I am wondering if the greater context of the translation caused the author to choose "vegetable." I also note that the "original sentence" is in english. Perhaps the original word draws less of a distinction between fruit and vegetable than the english words (more generic, like "edibles.")

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It mentions "edible fruits", which is pretty similar to vegetables. There's no such thing as a "fruit garden".

Comment: @Barmar Certainly there is: a fruit garden is just an alternative term for an orchard (though usually referring to smaller, less commercial ones, not huge plantation-like ones). Fruits (edible or not) and vegetables are similar to me, but far from the same thing—and there's a fairly clear distinction in what I'd expect to find in which type of garden. But as Yorik says, that same distinction may be different—or may not exist at all—in Croatian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The British English definition of garden:

From [ODO:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/garden)

> A piece of ground adjoining a house, in which grass, flowers, and shrubs may be grown.

From [Cambridge Dictionaries:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/garden):

> uk (us *yard*) a piece of land next to and belonging to a house, where flowers and other plants are grown, and often containing an area of grass:

If the house and garden were on a large plot of land, and the garden wasn't immediately adjoining the house (I don't know if this actually is the case in the book, but it certainly sometimes is the case in real life), I don't know if *garden* would be the right word in British English.

And I also assume that in British English, if you modify *garden* with something, as in *vegetable garden* or *flower garden*, there's no longer an implication that the garden is the area surrounding the house.

NEW EDIT: Let me add that the best translation would probably be *gardens*, and that in this case *garden* (despite its usual meaning of AmE *yard* in British English) is probably still better than *vegetable garden*. The word *garden* seems to have meant the same thing in the U.S. and the U.K. until sometime in the 20th century—consider the book *The Secret Garden* by Frances Hodgson Burnett, published in 1911. And [Samuel Johnson's Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=8cE_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PT7&dq=dictionary+English&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUzv_dp7rSAhXGQiYKHfNUAo44ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=gar&f=false) (1818) defines it as

> A piece of ground enclosed, and cultivated with extraordinary care, planted with herbs and fruits for food, or laid out for pleasure.

So the American meaning of *garden* should not be unknown to readers in the U.K.

Comment: Nice description, but coming to the question, why vegetable?

Comment: @Josh: assuming you have to put an adjective before it to keep it from meaning *yard*, I think you have a limited number of choices: *vegetable garden* and *flower garden* are by far the most common, but I think you could also use *fruit garden*. None of these are totally accurate.

Comment: So, a literary licence of the translator?

Comment: @Josh: Actually, I think the best translation into BrE might be *the gardens*. But maybe the translator didn't think of that.

Comment: Peter, +1 for a good answer and comments, but what is a "fruit garden" if not an orchard? (Perhaps my *almost* lifelong residence in California has me thinking of the miles and miles of arrow-straight orchards where much of America's fruit supply is grown.)

Comment: @Mark: what would you call a garden that contains raspberry bushes, strawberry plants, and melons? So it contains fruit-bearing plants, but not trees. (And Google shows that *fruit garden* is used, but is quite a bit rarer than *vegetable* or *flower garden*.)

Comment: adding a modifier to garden does not imply that its not surrounding the house